# jquery datatable some settings don't work

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have ajax based pagination and I have use different datatable with different settings and variable names, when I change page and create datatable, it'll be different features.

For example: One table has bFilter:false and second table has bFilter:true, but there is no search filter box in second table.

How Do I solve this?

I use [dataTable 1.9.4](http://datatables.net/index)

Second table's code is below:

```
var videoListDataTable = videoListTable.dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bFilter": true,     "bRetrieve": true,
        <?php if (isset($forRelation)): ?>
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        <?php endif; ?>
        "sAjaxSource": "video/tableData",
        "oLanguage": BIP.dataTableLocalization,
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
            oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
            });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            {"sTitle": "Id", "mData": "id", "bSortable": false},
            {"sTitle": "Video Başlığı", "mData": "title", "bSortable": false},
            {"sTitle": "Açıklama", "mData": "description", "bSortable": false},
            {"sTitle": "Thumbnail", "mData": "cdn_thumbnail", "bSortable": false,"fnRender":function(obj){
                //  debugger;
                var sReturn = obj.aData["cdn_thumbnail"]
                var returnButton = "<img src='"+sReturn+"' height='25px' width='60px'/>";
                return returnButton;
            }},
            {
                "sTitle": "Seçim",
                "sClass": "text-centered",
                "mData": null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (obj) {
                    var sReturn = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];
                    var returnButton = "<input class='btn blue' type='button' style='float: right' onclick='BIP.video.table.videoSelectedForRelation(this);return false;' name='" + sReturn + "' value='Seç'></input>";
                    return returnButton;
                },"sWidth": "25%"
            },
            {
                "sTitle": "Düzenle",
                "sClass": "text-centered",
                "mData": null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "fnRender": function (obj) {
                    var sReturn = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];
                    var returnButton = "<input class='btn blue' type='button' style='float: none' onclick='BIP.video.detailClickedFromTable(this);return false;' name='" + sReturn + "' value='Düzenle'></input>";
                    return returnButton;
                },"sWidth": "25%"
            }
        ],
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            $(nRow).attr("id","video_table_video_id_"+aData["id"]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My friend extends dataTable and this extensions corrupts the dataTable.

Problem is

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "sDom": "<'collapse'<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }
});
```